# What is the best way for getting difference between records' column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model `CounterRecord` and column there `data`. Records list:

```
r1.data = 10
r2.data = 12
r3.data = 15
r4.data = 20
```

I would like to get differences between current and previous record `[10,2,3,5]`. Does Rails have default way do that?

Comment: I don't think *Rails* a has default way. You need to use plain *SQL*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `Rails` or `ActiveRecord` has such stuff, but it can be easily done with little bit of ruby as:

```
CounterRecord.pluck(:data).each_with_index.map { |c,i| a[0] == c ? c : (a[i-1].to_i - c).abs }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Do the rails have default way do that?

No.

---

Possible solution:

```
CounterRecord.pluck(:data).each_cons(2).map { |first, second| second - first }
```

NOTE: with big amount of records this will easily kill your memory.

Comment: @Ilya true. Edited

Comment: I tried with `each_slice` earlier, it doesn't give desired output..did you execute it?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon, probably you should use `.to_a` after `each_slice`.

Comment: @Ilya `to_a` is not needed here.

Comment: Nope, the issue is in the `slicing` itself.. `[10, 12, 15, 20].each_slice(2).to_a` returns `[[10, 12], [15, 20]]` and required is something like this `[[10, 12], [12, 15], [15, 20]]`

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon it should have been `each_cons(2)`. I had a long break :D

Comment: aah..that's something new, I didn't know that..thanx. PS, you will need `to_a` after that and also a check for first element ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no default way to do as such.